# take more than one word into a string in java

Tags: java

hi i can not take more than one word in java with using nextline() method but when i use just next() method it takes just one word of the hole sentences. ;

```
public void entertext(){
    setparagnum();
    System.out.println("Enter line number in paragraph "+getparagnum());
    tempint=sc.nextInt();
    setlinenumber(tempint);
    System.out.println(getlinenumber());
    System.out.println("Enter text:");

    sc.skip("\n");

    text=sc.nextLine();

    settext(text);
    System.out.println(gettext());
    Paragraph temp=new Paragraph();
    temp.line_number=tempint;
    temp.string=text;
    temp.paragraph_number=getparagnum();
    if(tempint > myListOfParagraphs.size()){
        tempint = myListOfParagraphs.size();
    }
    if(tempint != 0 && tempint < myListOfParagraphs.size()){
        tempint = tempint - 1;
    }

    myListOfParagraphs.add(tempint, temp);


}
```

if i can take it than i try to take it in linkedlist which is myListOfParagraphs .

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: i want to take a sentences from user while they press enter but this code is not run it.